# Calling parent method from child window through delegate

Tags: c#

I have a parent form (MainForm), from which i call a wpf window (ChildWPF). 
In the parent window I have some data access methods. I need a way to call them from ChildWPF and have them return stuff to me. I wanted to do this through delegates (I dont want to pass MainForm as referance).

In ChildWPF:

```
public delegate List<string> MainFormMethod();
```

Now I cant seem to find a way to connect the hanlder that I am declaring in MainForm with my ChildWPF. Maybe using events is a better aproach?

Comment: That is not an option here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract data access methods to `ISomeDataAccess` interface and transfer data access logic from `MainForm` to class that realize this interface. After this you may share this class in `ChildWpf` too. Send instance of `ISomeDataAccess` interface as contructor parameter when create your `ChildWpf` form.
**Edit:**
Create interface with part of data access layer only needed for `ChildWpf` in ChildWpf project. You may implement this inreface in your `DataAccess` class direct or create intermediate adapter class.
Direct implementation:

```
public class DataAccess : IChildDataAccess
{
    public void SomeDataLogic1()
    {}

    public void SomeDataLogic2()
    {}

    public void SomeDataLogic3()
    {}
}

public interface IChildDataAccess
{
    void SomeDataLogic1();
    void SomeDataLogic3();
}
```

Or with intermediate class:

```
public class DataAccess
{
    public void SomeDataLogic1()
    {}

    public void SomeDataLogic2()
    {}

    public void SomeDataLogic3()
    {}
}

public class ChildDataAccess : IChildDataAccess
{
    private readonly DataAccess _dataAccess;

    public ChildDataAccess( DataAccess dataAccess )
    {
        if ( dataAccess == null )
            throw new ArgumentException( nameof( dataAccess ) );
        _dataAccess = dataAccess;
    }

    public void SomeDataLogic1()
    {
        _dataAccess.SomeDataLogic1();
    }

    public void SomeDataLogic3()
    {
        _dataAccess.SomeDataLogic3();
    }
}

public interface IChildDataAccess
{
    void SomeDataLogic1();
    void SomeDataLogic3();
}
```

Comment: The application "MainForm" is huge. MainForm has a referance to ChildWPF. In the MainForm project there is a class that has all the data access methods so I can not reference it from my project.

Comment: @cantdoanything33 i add update to my answer.